# How do I fix this Joomla white screen error?

Tags: joomla, screen

Joomla q.

I tried updating my Joomla site, and that failed and I got a basic html version of my site. I tried to downgrade by extracting a former version of Joomla in the root folder. when this failed I tried to change it again the same way.

This gave me a white screen on both admin side and front end. After following the first few steps [here](https://www.collectiveray.com/joomla/joomla-tutorials/joomla-blank-page.html)

I'm finally getting this error:

> ***Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'ini_set' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /home/*****/public_html/configuration.php on line 98*** (asterisks added)

Comment: Ok so I re-read the error and removed what it was indicating on line 98 and now this is the error: *Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/******/public_html/libraries/joomla/registry/registry.php on line 342

Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/******/public_html/libraries/joomla/registry/registry.php on line 342

Fatal error: Class 'Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin' not found in /home/******/public_html/plugins/system/sessiongc/sessiongc.php on line 22*

Comment: Please always display all question details in the question (please edit your question, then delete your comment).  Better yet, post your Joomla question(s) on Joomla Stack Exchange where a dedicated and experienced audience can offer support.  What was your previous Joomla version?  And what version of Joomla are you upgrading to?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the code from your `configuration.php` file around line 98?

Comment: There's a separate joomla stackexchange site that is the best place to get your answer [joomla.se].    It's not really designed to do the series of actions you have done but if you database hasn't been damaged (or you had a backup -- right?) you can probably recover.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any `ini_set` function call in the `configuration.php` file. Your website is likely hacked - you should proceed accordingly. First cleanup  your `configuration.php` file and then try [this guide](https://www.itoctopus.com/a-super-quick-guide-to-deal-with-a-hacked-joomla-website) for quickly cleaning Joomla sites. Please note that usage of this guide is at your own risk and you must always backup your Joomla site before doing this. Also note that if your Joomla site has core modifications then they will be wiped out. Finally, keep in mind that you may still have reminiscent hacked files on your site even after implementing the above, so you clean those as well.